# How to make UEFI Ubuntu bootable from MBR drive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, mbr

I have Ubuntu installed on an external HDD (MBR Partition Table). The USB Live Disk was UEFI and although I instructed Ubuntu installer to install Grub in external HDD it managed to install Grub in internal one. For compatibility with older hardware I choose to use MBR on external HDD, but I accidently installed Ubuntu in UEFI. `grub-install grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdc` does not work. It shows the following error:

`grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before going further, you should back up a bit. The key point for system compatibility is not the partition table type; it's the boot loader. Every computer has firmware that controls the boot process, and the boot loader must be able to work with that firmware. For x86 and x86-64 systems, the firmware is usually either the old-style BIOS or the newer EFI (or UEFI, which is just EFI 2.x). Either type of firmware can boot from either MBR or GPT disks, although BIOS systems *usually* employ MBR and EFI systems *usually* employ GPT.

The point of this is that you must assess whether the computers you want to boot use BIOSes, EFIs, or a mixture of both, and pick a suitable boot loader. It's possible to install both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode boot loaders, but this can be tricky, especially if you want to use GRUB for both modes. If you must support both boot modes, I recommend using GRUB for BIOS and something else for EFI, or vice-versa. This means you'll have to learn about alternatives to GRUB.

GRUB is available for many different types of firmware, including both BIOS and EFI. An "EFI-mode install" of Ubuntu just means an Ubuntu installation that includes the EFI version of GRUB (or, in principle, some other EFI boot loader, but GRUB is the only one that the Ubuntu installation tools will set up automatically). Note that when you install GRUB in Ubuntu, this involves both setting up a bunch of scripts and copies of binaries in the Linux filesystem *and* copying relevant pieces to privileged locations on the disk (and, in the case of EFI, registering NVRAM entries). In other words, you cannot install a BIOS-mode GRUB using the EFI-mode GRUB package you have installed on your computer right now. To install a BIOS-mode GRUB, you must do one of a few things:

- Install the BIOS-mode GRUB package (`grub-pc`), which will also uninstall the EFI-mode package
- Get the GRUB source code, or perhaps a binary build without actually installing a Debian package, and install it manually (a tricky process)
- Install GRUB to the boot medium from a live disk.

In most cases, the [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can be used to install a different variety of GRUB than what's already there. The trick is to boot whatever disk you use to run Boot Repair in the desired boot mode -- if you boot in BIOS mode, Boot Repair will install BIOS-mode GRUB; and if you boot in EFI mode, it will install EFI-mode GRUB. There's also the complication that you want to install to a USB device; I'm not sure if Boot Repair will install GRUB to that disk or try to install to your internal disk.

There's another complication for EFI-mode boots of external disks: Instead of installing to a conventional OS-specific location (`EFI/ubuntu`, in the case of Ubuntu), the boot loader on removable disks should normally be installed to the *fallback filename* of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. This may require manual copying of boot loader files.